# Comparar lista de valores con rango y extraer los que caen fuera del rango

Tags: r, condiciones, comparaciones

Estoy realizando un control de calidad de una tabla y me gustaría saber como puedo comprobar si los valores de una columna están dentro de un rango o lista de valores, pero que me devuelva un único valor (TRUE o FALSE) cuando al menos uno de los valores de la lista no coincida con el rango. En el caso de que de FALSE, querría que extrajese solo los registros que no están en el rango.

```
list.comprobar <- sample(1:7,15,replace = TRUE)
rango <- 1:6
```

Solo he conseguido que salga con todos los registros de esta forma:

```
list.comprobar %in% rango
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Mi idea original era realizar un condicional con if de forma que si todos los valores de la lista estén dentro del rango devuelva un mensaje "OK" y si hay un valor fuera del rango que imprima el mensaje "Fuera de rango" y saque una tabla con los registros que estén fuera del rango.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `all()` para validar que todos los valores de un vector sean `TRUE`:

```
if (all(list.comprobar %in% rango)) {
   print("OK")
} else {
   print("ERROR")
}
```

`all()` incorpora el clásico parámetro `na.rm` para eventualmente no considerar los `NA`.